# WooCommerce shop page display products above $50

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I have coded up a woocommerce theme and the website has a shop page. You can find out the shop page http://bit.ly/1TSMKrV

Now, I need few things to happen on this page

1. The products which are priced more than $50 should only display
2. The products must be sorted by popularity
3. The filters on the left side must function properly

I have tried to place the following code above the while loop

```
$args = array(
      'post_type' => 'product',
      'paged' => $page,
      'posts_per_page' => 15,
      'meta_key'=>'_sale_price',
      'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => '_sale_price',
            'value' => '50',
            'compare' => '>',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        )
    )
 );
```

But this code just fulfils the first condition and not the other. For time being, I have removed the code and just used the default while loop that Woo Commerce provides.

Let me know where I am going wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried adding multiple arrays to your `meta_query`? One for sale price, one for popularity? Popularity should be a `rating` key.

Comment: @dingo_d nope. I haven't. Can you please tell me how to do ?

Comment: to your query after array with `_sale_price` just add another array (separate the two by ,). `array('key'=> 'rating')` . You need to see what values to put in this array, and you should add order in the main arguments array.